# How does load balancing / VIP works with overlay networks?

Tags: networking, docker-swarm

I'm trying to understand how the built-in Docker load balancing / VIP works with overlay networks. To better explain how I understand this, I've put together a diagram. My hope is that someone can confirm or reject my understanding.

Let's say I've got two services running in a Docker Swarm : `webserver` and `api`. Both of these two services have been scaled to two instances. These instances runs on **NODE A** and **NODE B**.

1. Someone out there in the world makes a request which somehow hits **NODE A**.
2. `iptables` on **NODE A** will `DNAT` the request to the ingress-sbox on **NODE A**.
3. The `ingress-sbox` (let's just regard it as a black box) decides that the request should go to webserver on **NODE B**.
4. The `ingress-sbox` sends the request out on the "api" overlay network bridge, and the request gets routed via the `vxlan` tunnel to the "api" overlay network bridge on **NODE B**.
5. The webserver container on **NODE B** receives the request via the "api" overlay network bridge.

Is this a fair understanding of how incoming requests will traverse an overlay network?

*...and a followup question; what happens when a request goes from `webserver` to `api` via a load balancer (`ingress-sbox`). Will requests always be load balanced through the `ingress-sbox` on the same host as the request originates from? If this is the case, I assume this means that a request to a service VIP always gets routed to the `ingress-sbox` which runs on the very same node as where a request is made from?*

[image]

Comment: I did some research, and came up with the following explanation : https://github.com/octetnest/docs/blob/master/DockerInternalLoadBalancing.md